# Many-to-many relationships: better OTLT or 48 association/junction tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i'm  working on a database model with a lot of many-to-many relationships.

In my scheme there is a group of 6 tables (let's say T1, T1 ... T6) and another group of 8 tables (let's say S1,S2... S8). Let's assume each table (T1, T1 ... T6, S1,S2... S8) has a PK. 
Each table of the first group is associated with every table of the second group and i need to store information about the relationship like you can see in this simple example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

How to deal with this situation?

Would a One True Lookup Table (OTLT) be preferable to a 6 x 8 associative tables solution? 
Does a better solution exists?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

-----EDIT---

I'm uploading some image to make the problem clear:

The problem:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltCZx.png

I know that the OTLT approach implies less performance, but on the other side is the fastest way of modeling the problem. 
Explosion Pills reccomended me to merge all T1,... T6 tables into one big table. That solution in not possible (at least not in that model) because of other relationship which T1... T6 have with the other (not mentioned) tables of the schema.

Comment: Why do you have `T1`-`T6` instead of just a single `T`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. T1....T6 tables store different type of data and that's the reason why i created 6 different tables. For sake of simplicity i named them using the same letter T, but they are logically different.

Comment: That does not necessarily mean they need to be different tables, but it depends.  Even though your structure is very large, it may be helpful if you can share what it is specifically

Comment: What do you think the benefit is if you to go with the OTLT?

Comment: I edited my question and added some more (hope helpfully) details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see my OTLT discussion here:

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/one-true-lookup-table-discussion/

But basically, with OTLT, you run the risk of putting errant data in a table.

Let's say you have an Employee table, and one of the "lookups" is EmployeeStatus. Employee.EmpStatus column for example.

Your OTLT table has multiple Employee-Status'es.....but it has alot of other things.  Like "OrderStatus", which has nothing to do with Employee-Status.

So what do you do?

My link above shows code uses a check-constraint to make sure you only put valid values from the OTLT in the Employee.EmpStatus column.

However, while it protects data integrity, it comes at a cost.  Every insert has to do the check-constraint check (duh)........

So I try to find balance in the force.  If the Lookup is very generic, I put it in the OTLT.  Once it does anything beyond, I move it.

And here is my other trick.
On a high concurrency database, I will use the check-constraint in DEV and QA.  But in production I will disable it, at least as long as there aren't any issues.

Answer (score 0):

As Joe Celko explains [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/),  "One True look-up Table (OTLT) is a nightmare that keeps showing up" : bad data, large data, locks, bad query plans and performance problems, bottleneck in your application, unreadable queries ...

Perhaps you could redesign your tables so that they are just a little bit more generic and share some common information, without ending in the OTLT?